# For loop not showing on template

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm trying to display the news on my website but for some reason its not showing, the first loop is ok, but the second one is not displaying anything where it suposed to be.

Here are my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for cat in cats %}
        <div class="col-lg-6 py-3">
            <div class="bg-light py-2 px-4 mb-3">
                <h3 class="m-0">{{cat.category_name}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-3 carousel-item-2 position-relative">
                {% for news in category.news_set.all %}
                {% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
                <div class="position-relative">
                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="{{news.cover.url}}" style="object-fit: cover;">
                    <div class="overlay position-relative bg-light">
                        <div class="mb-2" style="font-size: 13px;">
                            <a href="">{{news.title}}</a>
                            <span class="px-1">/</span>
                            <span>{{news.created_at}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <a class="h4 m-0" href="">{{news.description}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def home (request):   
cats = Category.objects.all()[0:4]
articles = Article.objects.all()    
return render (request,'pages/home.html',
context={
'articles': articles,
'cats': cats,
})
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=65)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=165)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='newsroom/covers/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
        default=None,)
```

Comment: Add your model .

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-3 carousel-item-2 position-relative">
            {% for news in cat.news_set.all %}
            {% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="{{news.cover.url}}" style="object-fit: cover;">
                <div class="overlay position-relative bg-light">
                    <div class="mb-2" style="font-size: 13px;">
                        <a href="">{{news.title}}</a>
                        <span class="px-1">/</span>
                        <span>{{news.created_at}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <a class="h4 m-0" href="">{{news.description}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am assuming that `news` is a relationship to category.

Comment: no its not, its just for the for loop, i will post my models also that i forgot sorry